# How to change timezone without changing the time?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a timestamp 2018-01-01 18:20:23.11 which is in UTC. I need to print this in a different format but retain the UTC timezone. However if I use SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM YYYY yyyy  kk:mm z"), it takes my current timezone and gives me 01 Jan 2018 18:20 EST. I want this to print 01 Jan 2018 18:20 UTC. Doing a Timezone.getTimeZone("UTC") converts this time to UTC (does a +4 to hours)which is not the desired result.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: See related Question, [*Changing time zone with Calendar object from EEST to HST changes the time-of-day unexpectedly*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51257965/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
    DateTimeFormatter newFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu HH:mm z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String originalTimestamp = "2018-01-01 18:20:23.11";
    String differentFormat = LocalDateTime.parse(originalTimestamp, originalFormatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"))
            .format(newFormatter);
    System.out.println(differentFormat);
```

This prints

```
01 Jan 2018 18:20 UTC
```

### `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")` or `ZoneOffset.UTC`?

A possibly nerdy edit: I had first written `.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` in the conversion. I usually use `ZoneOffset.UTC` to denote UTC and consider this the nice and idiomatic way of specifying it. However in the case of your code, this resulted in the zone being given as `Z` in the output where you had asked for `UTC`. Using `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")` instead gives you what you want. I can find no other way of making sure that the zone is formatted as `UTC` (save hardcoding `UTC` in the format pattern string, but that would be an ugly hack).

BTW `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC").normalized()` returns `ZoneOffset.UTC` (at least on my Java 10, but I expect it to be the case always).

### SimpleDateFormat vs. java.time

`SimpleDateFormat` is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. I recommend you avoid it. It is correct, as you have observed, that it uses your JVM’s default time zone. There is a way to persuade it to do differently, but I would not bother.

`java.time` is the modern Java date and time API. It came out in 2014 as a replacement for the old and poorly designed date and time classes. IMHO it is so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`

Comment: Why not use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")`?

Comment: Interesting that `ZoneOffset.UTC` and `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")` show different behavior. Thanks. I suggest adding that as a note of interest in your Answer.

Comment: wow, that was awesome, great java to change a time zone we need that much code, isn't it a shame?