# Changing time zone with Calendar object from EEST to HST changes the time-of-day unexpectedly

Tags: java, date, timezone, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have some `TimeStamp` and I have date format `"EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a zzz"`. But I don't know how I can show this timestamp with timezone. When I trying to show it I get wrong DateTime or wrong timezone

example1:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(device.getUpdatedDate().getTime())); // here is 2018-07-09 20:02:26.506000
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(EMAIL_DATE_FORMAT);
sdf.format(calendar.getTime()); // i have wrong timezone
```

and i get `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 08:02 PM EEST`

but when i add `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("HST"));` i have right timezone and wrong time
`Monday, Jul 09, 2018 07:02 AM HST`

expected result `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 08:02 PM HST`

actual results: `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 08:02 PM EEST`
or `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 07:02 AM HST`

Comment: Well you could have an error in your code. Would you like to show it? Some people here are able to find errors in code they are looking at. But without code, that is quite hard to do...

Comment: what you have tried so far please post your code

Comment: Pleae study and apply the concept of making a [mcve].

Comment: Please read the MCVE link and try harder to create one.

Comment: Add some sets of sample data, the output and desired output in comparison.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher updated the question

Comment: Be aware that a `Date` hasn’t got a time zone. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). Is `device.getUpdatedDate()` a `Date` too?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They are not only long outdated, they are also poorly designed and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Assuming you have got a legacy `Date` object, first convert to the modern `Instant` class, then do further opreations from there: `device.getUpdatedDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a zzz", Locale.US))`.

Comment: What `TimeStamp`? I see only `Calendar` in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- You are seeing a **feature, not a bug**, adjusting same moment to another time zone.

  - **8 PM in eastern Europe is also 7 AM in Hawaii.**
- Use real time zone names, not 3-4 letter pseudo zones.
- Use modern *java.time* classes, not poorly-designed legacy classes.

### Same moment: Call `withZoneSameInstant`

You adjusted from one time zone 3 hours *ahead* of UTC to another zone 10 hours *behind* UTC, for a total difference of 13 hours. Understand that 8 PM in one place is simultaneously 7 AM in the other.

Note our call to `withZoneSameInstant` (‘Instant’) in the following code.

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 
    2018 , 7 , 9 , 20 , 2 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Europe/Athens" )  // 8 PM in Greece.
)
.withZoneSameInstant(                                             // Adjust into another time zone to view the same moment with another wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Honolulu" )                               // 7 AM in Hawaii.
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-07-09T07:02-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

### Different moment: Call `withZoneSameLocal`

Apparently you wanted a different moment, a different point on the timeline, that has the same date and same time-of-day but a different time zone.

Note our call to `withZoneSameLocal` (‘Local’, not ‘Instant’) in the following code.

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 
    2018 , 7 , 9 , 20 , 2 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Europe/Athens" )  // 8 PM in Greece.
)
.withZoneSameLocal(                                               // Different moment, coincidentally having the same date and same time-of-day. But different time zone means this is a different point on the timeline.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Honolulu" )                               // Also 8 PM in Hawaii, which happens many hours later than 8 PM in Greece. Different moment, same wall-clock time.
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-07-09T20:02-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

---

## Details

### Real time zone

`HST` & `EEST` are pseudo-zones, not real time zones. Avoid these 3-4 letter codes as they are not standardized and are not even unique(!).

Use real time zone names as defined in [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) by the [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). See a [list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (possibly outdated). These names are in `Continent/Region` format such as `America/Montreal` or `Europe/Tallinn`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Vilnius" ) ;
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the terribly troublesome classes `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`. These were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Working with *java.time* is much clearer and easier.

Let's get your starting point. I am guessing that by [`EEST`](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eest) you had in mind one of the eastern European time zones. I am choosing one arbitrarily.

```
ZoneId zAthens = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Athens" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JULY , 9 ) ;  // 2018-07-09.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 20 , 2 ) ;  // 8:02 PM.
ZonedDateTime zdtAthens = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , zAthens ) ;
```

Generate a `String` representing the value of that [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. By default, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String outputAthens = zdtAthens.toString() ;  // Generate `String` in a format extending standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-07-09T20:02+03:00[Europe/Athens]

By `HST` I guess you mean Hawaii time. The proper name for that zone is `Pacific/Honolulu`.

```
ZoneId zHonolulu = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Honolulu" ) ;
```

Let's adjust our Athens moment into this other zone for Hawaii. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time. Imagine a pair of friends in each place calling each and simultaneously looking up at a clock on their wall. Each sees a different time-of-day and possibly a different date, nevertheless they experience the same simultaneous moment, same point on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtHonolulu = zdtAthens.withZoneSameInstant( zHonolulu ) ;  // Same moment (same `Instant` inside the `ZonedDateTime`) but a different time zone.
```

On that date, Honolulu is ten hours behind UTC while Athens is three hours ahead. That is a total delta of thirteen hours. So, 8 PM (20:00) minus 13 is 7 AM. We expect to see 7 AM in Hawaii. Let's verify, by generating another string in ISO 8601 format.

```
String outputHonolulu = zdtHonolulu.toString() ;  // Generate `String` representing the value of the `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

> 2018-07-09T07:02-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

Sure enough, 7 AM.

Perhaps what you wanted was the same date and same time-of-day located in Hawaii. This would mean you are *not* representing the same simultaneous moment. You would be representing a different point on the timeline, off by several hours.

The `ZonedDateTime` does provide for this function. Call `ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameLocal` meaning conceptually: Use the same internal `LocalDate` and the same internal `LocalTime`, but use a different assigned `ZoneId`.

```
ZonedDateTime eightPmOnJuly9InPacificHonolulu = zdtAthens.withZoneSameLocal( zHonolulu) ; 
String outputDifferentMoment= eightPmOnJuly9InPacificHonolulu.toString() ;
```

> 2018-07-09T20:02-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

#### UTC

All this flipping around between time zones can drive a person batty. Get grounded by focusing on UTC. Think of UTC as *The One True Time*, and all other zones are but mere variations.

To adjust from a time zone to UTC, extract a `Instant` object from our `ZonedDateTime` objects. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instantAthens = zdtAthens.toInstant() ;
Instant instantHonolulu = zdtHonolulu.toInstant() ;
Instant instantDifferentMoment = eightPmOnJuly9InPacificHonolulu.toInstant() ;
```

> 2018-07-09T17:02:00Z
>
> 2018-07-09T17:02:00Z
>
> 2018-07-10T06:02:00Z

The `Z` on the end means UTC, is pronounced *Zulu*, and is defined by ISO 8601 and other standards.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `device.getUpdatedDate()` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp`, for example `2018-07-09 20:02:26.506000`. I assume that (contrary to the idea of a timestamp) this date and time was produced without time zone, but that you know that it is in Pacific/Honolulu time zone (Hawaii Standard Time or HST, used in Hawaii all year).

If you are getting the `Timestamp` from an SQL database (as would be normal) — don’t. The `Timestamnp` class is long outdated and quite confusing. Assuming you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, you may get an instance of the modern `LocalDateTime` from the database instead. Assuming that `rs` is your result set and your column is named `updated_date` (I trust you to tailor the code to your situation):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(EMAIL_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
    LocalDateTime updatedDateTime 
            = rs.getObject("updated_date", LocalDateTime.class);
    ZonedDateTime timeOnHawaii 
            = updatedDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
    String formattedDateTime = timeOnHawaii.format(formatter);
```

If your timestamp is stored in the database with time zone information you can do even better by using `Instant.class` instead and be sure to get the same point in time as in the database. The exact possibilities depend on the capabilities of your JDBC driver.

In case you cannot avoid getting the `Timestamp`, convert it like this:

```
    ZonedDateTime timeOnHawaii = device.getUpdatedDate()
            .toLocalDateTime()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
```

With your example `Timestamp` and the formatter from my first code snippet above this prints:

> Monday, Jul 09, 2018 08:02 PM HST

(assuming that `EMAIL_DATE_FORMAT` is defined as `"EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a zzz"`).

### What went wrong in your code?

One confusing thing about `Timestamp` is that it represents a point in time (without time zone) but has often been used for representing a date and time of day (also without time zone) instead. So your `Timestamp` of 2018-07-09 20:02:26.506000 really holds the value (point in time) equal to 2018-07-09 20:02:26.506000 Eastern European Summer Time (EEST, as used in Украина/Ukraine) but is confusingly used by `device.getUpdatedDate()` to mean 2018-07-09 20:02:26.506000 in Hawaii. Neither `Date` nor `SimpleDateFormat` change the point in time, which is why they give you `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 08:02 PM EEST` or the equivalent `Monday, Jul 09, 2018 07:02 AM HST`.

### Links:

- More about the confusion of `Timestamp` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779109/5772882) to [this question: Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.